# How do I solve volumes bounded by solids using slices?

Tags: calculus

How to find the volume of the solid bounded by the paraboloid $y^2+4z^2=x$ and the plane $x=4$ Using the slice (ellipse) indicated in the figure to compute the volume?[image]

[Ellipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sCs4.png)

Comment: You have to put `$` signs around the MathJax expressions for the formatting to work.

Comment: That seems like a strange picture to me.  Why wouldn't one take slices parallel to the $yz$-plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to approximate the volume by slices parallel to the $yz$-plane.  The slices are elliptical cylinders so the volume is the height times the area of the base.

The cross-section at height $x$ is the ellipse$${y^2\over(\sqrt{x})^2}+{z^2\over(\sqrt{x}/2)^2}=1$$ whose area is ${\pi x\over 2}$.  Taking this as the base, and the height as $dx$ we get $$V=\int_0^4 {\pi x\over2}\mathrm{dx}$$

Comment: can this still be integrated though?

Comment: @AnthonyFernandez Surely you know how to integrate $x\mathrm{dx}$

Comment: yep haha thanks @saulspatz

Comment: the answer is 4π right?

Comment: @AnthonyFernandez Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}&\int_{y^2+4z^2\leq 4}\ (4-y^2-4z^2)\ dA \\&=
\int_{y=-2}^{y=2}\int_{ -\sqrt{\frac{4-y^2}{4}} }^{
\sqrt{\frac{4-y^2}{4}} } \ (4-y^2-4z^2)\
 dzdy \\
 &=\int_{-2}^2\ \frac{2}{3}(4-y^2)\sqrt{4-y^2}\ dy \\&=
   \int^{\pi}_0\ \frac{32}{3} \cdot\sin^4 t\ dt\\&=
4\pi
\end{align*} since $$ \sin^4 t
=(1-\cos^2 t)^2 =\bigg(1- \frac{\cos\ 2t+1}{2} \bigg)^2 = \frac{3}{8}
 +C\cos\ 2t +D\cos\ 4t $$

Answer (score 1):

First you find the intersection of the plane $x=4$ and the parabolid $y^2+4z^2=x$

That gives you an ellipse $y^2/4+z^2=1$

Then you form a double integral on the ellipse with the integrand being the function $4-y^2-4z^2$

Follow the proof given by HK Lee for the rest of the story.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the OP is asking for.  I think the question means that he wants to integrate the volume of an elliptical cylinder as $x$ runs from $0$ to $4$.

Comment: thank you @saulspatz, I really dont know how to solve this. do you have a solution you could show me on how to do this?